# How to add particular resource at image src in content received from evernote

Tags: python, hex, evernote

I want to map resource tags in content to resources received from evernote.

Resources -
I am able to see all resources fetched from evernote,
eg:

```
for r in resources:
    file_content = r.data.body
    file_type = r.mime
    filename = r.attributes.fileName
    hashvalue = r.data.bodyHash 
    //i want this resource to bind to its image tag
```

HTML -

```html
<html>
<body>
<div>ddkfmdk</div>
<div>
<br/>
</div>
<br/>
<img class="attach_img" src="/images/ef89ec799076f38a6f50b2acd58a5f4f.png"/>
br/>
<img class="attach_img" src="/images/ef011616fa96b4550dae7267ecee68fd.png"/>
</body>
</html>
```

We receive list of resources from evernote, but how would I bind these resources to particular image tags

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: @enderland plz find updated code

Comment: What's an example of a resource tag do you want map?

Comment: @martineau We receive list of resources from evernote, but how would I bind these resources to particular image tag

Comment: I was trying to identify what value in your code might be able to be used as a "key". The usual way to map things in Python is via a dictionary, which associates "keys" with "values". The keys can be anything hashable and the values can be (almost) anything. So to do what you want, build a dictionary that uses these resource tags as keys. You can make the value associated with it a `list` or other container if there's more than one of them.

Comment: thanx for that @martineau, but i understand python dict, problem here is - image source says - src="/images/ef89ec799076f38a6f50b2acd58a5f4f.png", but there is no image at the location, and i am unable to find a solution. plz tell

Comment: Oh, sorry — that's certainly not clear from your question. All I can say is the value of `src` looks like a path, so it might be relatively to where the html file resides or the evernote website.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125631/discussion-between-keshav-and-martineau).

Comment: I need a way to know which specific resource should i add at that source path